# Status bar android

Tags: android, java

Как в android 5 поменять цвет в status bar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[на, лови.](http://google.gik-team.com/?q=android+5+status+bar+color) должно помочь.

ЗЫ Ну почему, я , не занимающийся андроидом , нахожу ответ за милисекунды?

[guide 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522806/status-bar-color-not-showing-5-0-lollipop-android-studio-appcompat-v7r21) [guide 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192291/how-to-change-the-status-bar-color-in-android) [main guide](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)

Comment: Я искал и пытался сделать хотя бы на андроид 5, но у меня не получается, пишу в теме, `<item name="statusbar">#00FF00</item>` пишет, что такого параметра нету, ставлю `<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00FF00</item>`
статус бар такой же серый, пытался еще использовать стороннюю библиотеку для этого SystemInt, он должен был менять, но не получается, и да, вы правы, надо было объяснить, что я делал.